# Bootstrap with Responsive CSS Mask

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, svg, mask

I can't use width and height 100% to my class `svgmask` because bootstrap doesn't accept this value, so I can't get a responsive mask on my website. How can I fix it?

[**jsfiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/prvoq0e1/) - On example, `svgmask` width is set to 500px and height to 300px.

Comment: Yes. Only if you use a fixed width and height to `svgmask`. Try to change it to 100% and it will stop to work. I want a responsive element and not one with fixed size.

Comment: I have updated your css its working well with bootstrap, you just need to give height to parent eg 'body, html { height:100%}' check the fiddle -  jsfiddle.net/prvoq0e1/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

give

```
div#svgmask-img {
    background-size: contain;
}
```

```css
div.svgmask {
    mask: url(http://filedb.experts-exchange.com/incoming/2009/05_w22/144001/mask.png);
    -webkit-mask: url(http://filedb.experts-exchange.com/incoming/2009/05_w22/144001/mask.png) bottom left / contain no-repeat;
    -o-mask: url(http://filedb.experts-exchange.com/incoming/2009/05_w22/144001/mask.png) bottom left / contain no-repeat;
    -ms-mask: url(http://filedb.experts-exchange.com/incoming/2009/05_w22/144001/mask.png) bottom left / contain no-repeat;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  margin: 8px;
  height: 300px;
  width: 500px;
}

div#svgmask-img {
    background: url(http://27.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_lgcrktvVwG1qboti3o1_500.jpg) no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  position: absolute;
   top:0;
   left:0;
   right:0;
   bottom:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="svgmask"> <div id="svgmask-img"></div> </div>
```

**EDIT** 
For getting 100% height, you have to set 100% height for the body and html tags.

```css
body, html{
  height: 100%;
}

div.svgmask {
    mask: url(http://filedb.experts-exchange.com/incoming/2009/05_w22/144001/mask.png);
    -webkit-mask: url(http://filedb.experts-exchange.com/incoming/2009/05_w22/144001/mask.png) bottom left / contain no-repeat;
    -o-mask: url(http://filedb.experts-exchange.com/incoming/2009/05_w22/144001/mask.png) bottom left / contain no-repeat;
    -ms-mask: url(http://filedb.experts-exchange.com/incoming/2009/05_w22/144001/mask.png) bottom left / contain no-repeat;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  margin: 8px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;;
}

div#svgmask-img {
    background: url(http://27.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_lgcrktvVwG1qboti3o1_500.jpg) no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%;
  position: absolute;
   top:0;
   left:0;
   right:0;
   bottom:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="svgmask"> <div id="svgmask-img"></div> </div>
```

Comment: Do same thing using height and width 100% to svgmask element.

Comment: – Your code works but dont on bootstrap. I dont know why. [update] (https://jsfiddle.net/prvoq0e1/2/)

Comment: I will check this. Do you want the mask to get 100% height too ?

Comment: Check out this - https://jsfiddle.net/Jinukurian7/prvoq0e1/3/

Just remove the contain and add cover in "div.svgmask"